# qemu-system-x86 --enable-kvm Windows 2k12 R2 stuck at windows logo

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, libvirt

I am having an issue with kvm-qemu.

Host: Ubuntu
Guest OS is win2k12 R2.

When the VM is booted, some times it get stuck at windows log or it pass the windows log & get stuck at a black screen. I had to do a force shutdown through virt-manager to come out of it. Once turned off, If I start it back some times it boot up.

It's happening almost 8 times out of 10.

in htop (host) I see these running in loop.

[image: active processes]

I have almost 8 of them running at a time.

Found something suspicious over here in qemu logs;

[image: qemu log]

Comment: It looks like the guest OS isn't responding. This is not likely to be a problem with QEMU/KVM.

Comment: Guest is a fresh install. Also next time when the system bootsup, it gives message that the OS wasn't shutdown propperly. So, anyway I can isolate it and fix? Tried with 2 hosts and same issue.

Comment: Windows Startup Repair? I'm just guessing. You'd probably have to get help from a site that supports Windows, such as our sister site [su].

Answer (score 0):

Identified this as an issue with the ISO itself. 
Downloaded latest ISO & tested for a month. So far no issues.